# How to define recursive URL consumption logic

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest

Let's say I have the following relationships between my entities :

> Employee have many cars, car have many wheels, wheel have one manufacturer,
>   manufacturer have many employees.

What's the best way to **dynamically** expose the following endpoints using Spring Boot Rest API :

`/users/{id}`

`/users/{id}/wheels`

`/users/{id}/wheels/{id}/manufacturer/{id}/employees/{id}/`

`/users/{id}/wheels/{id}/manufacturer/{id}/employees/{id}/wheels/{id}/`

What's the proper architecture/logic I can implements in order to get the following endpoints and to consume the mentionned urls ?

Comment: Use a query string instead.

Comment: Can you please five me more details ? User Query Strings instead of what ?

Comment: If you structure your URL like `/uri/path?user={userid}&wheels={wheelsId}...` instead of having them in the URI then you can have spring Map all of them in any order to an object, ignoring missing/null ones.

Comment: Although granted the above solution is possibly not great for SEO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation... but this does not respond to the question the order is important to me.

Comment: Why is the order important?

Comment: The order will allow me to ensure the request is correct.
For example `/users/{id}/wheels/{id}/` (result is a wheel) is different from `/wheels/{id}/users/{id}` (result is a user), but `path?user={userid}&wheels={wheelsId}` won't allow me to distinguish between them.
Am I getting it wrong ?

Comment: You would have URI specify the resource you wanted i.e  `mysite.com/search/wheel` and the query string specifies the search parameters